# Have the notices to quit etc prescribed information regulations 1988 ever been subsequently altered or overridden?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research

Has [UKSI 1988/2201](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1988/2201/made) ever been amended, altered or otherwise affected by anything else given since it was made?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I've been unable to find any evidence of this being amended.